# Convert an Object to json

Tags: ios, json, nsmutabledictionary

I have one main entity class with name "Store" like :

Store.h :-

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SignIn.h"

@interface Store : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *storeId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *storeProfileId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *storeName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *storeRegion;

@property (nonatomic, retain) SignIn *signIn;

@end
```

Store.m :-

```
#import "Store.h"

@implementation Store

@synthesize storeId, storeProfileId, storeName, storeRegion, signIn;

- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [[Store alloc] init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        self.storeId = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"storeId"];
        self.storeProfileId = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"storeProfileId"];
        self.storeName = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"storeName"];
        self.storeRegion = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"storeRegion"];

        self.signIn = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"signIn"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:storeId forKey:@"storeId"];
    [coder encodeObject:storeProfileId forKey:@"storeProfileId"];
    [coder encodeObject:storeName forKey:@"storeName"];
    [coder encodeObject:storeRegion forKey:@"storeRegion"];

    [coder encodeObject:signIn forKey:@"signIn"];
}

@end
```

Here in Store class, i am taking one more class name "Sign In", that include some other attributes.

SignIn.h :-

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SignIn : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *inTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *outTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *isStatus;

@end
```

SignIn.m :-

```
#import "SignIn.h"

@implementation SignIn
@synthesize inTime, outTime, isStatus;

- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [[SignIn alloc] init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        self.inTime = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"inTime"];
        self.outTime = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"outTime"];
        self.isStatus = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"isStatus"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:inTime forKey:@"inTime"];
    [coder encodeObject:outTime forKey:@"outTime"];
    [coder encodeObject:isStatus forKey:@"isStatus"];
}

@end
```

Now i need to post this Store object on server. So I am creating dictionary using below code :

```
NSMutableArray *storeJSONArray=[NSMutableArray array];
    for (Store *store in array1) {

        NSMutableDictionary *storeJSON=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        [storeJSON setValue:store.storeId forKey:@"storeId"];
        [storeJSON setValue:store.storeProfileId forKey:@"storeProfileId"];
        [storeJSON setValue:store.storeName forKey:@"storeName"];
        [storeJSON setValue:store.storeRegion forKey:@"storeRegion"];


        //Sign In
        [storeJSON setValue:store.signIn.inTime forKey:@"inTime"];
        [storeJSON setValue:store.signIn.outTime forKey:@"outTime"];
        [storeJSON setValue:store.signIn.isStatus forKey:@"isStatus"];

        [storeJSONArray addObject:storeJSON];
    }

  NSMutableDictionary *dictionnary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dictionnary setObject:storeJSONArray forKey:@"Store"];

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionnary
                                                   options:kNilOptions
                                                     error:&error];

if (! jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
} else {
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

But as an output, i am getting jsonString value like :

```
{
    "Store": [
        {
            "storeId": "SGVM0001",
            "storeProfileId": "SG-12",
            "store_name": "Best Denki",
            "storeRegion": "Ngee Ann City",
            "inTime": "2013-12-05 11:03:00",
            "outTime": "2013-12-0511: 27: 00",
            "isStatus": "YES"
        }
    ]
}
```

But i need an output as :

```
{
    "Store": [
        {
            "storeId": "SGVM0001",
            "storeProfileId": "SG-12",
            "store_name": "Best Denki",
            "storeRegion": "Ngee Ann City",
            "signIn": {
                "inTime": "2013-12-05 11:03:00",
                "outTime": "2013-12-0511: 27: 00",
                "isStatus": "YES"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Can you please check my code and let me know what changes i need to do here for getting above output ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you need to create one more dictionary

```
NSDMutableDict *signInDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
 //Sign In
 [signInDic setValue:store.signIn.inTime forKey:@"inTime"];
 [signInDic setValue:store.signIn.outTime forKey:@"outTime"];
 [signInDic setValue:store.signIn.isStatus forKey:@"isStatus"];

 [storeJSON setObject:signInDic forKey:@"sign_in"];
```

Comment: @BhumeshwerThanks for giving me time. In actually, i have 6 sub entity class inside one main entity "Store". So like your above code i need to do for all. It means i need to create multiple dictionaries for sub entities.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSMutableDictionary  *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [dict setValue:store.dict.inTime forKey:@"inTime"];

      .......

      .....

    [storeJSON setObject:dict forKey:@"sign_in"];
```